# Add rows to a data set based on 2 grouping vectors

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like the picture below. For everyday NJ (person) and every stimulus/ProductName) I want to have 10 listed attributes. Currently only attributes that are used are listed (so a different number of attributes for different stimuli) but I want all 10 listed each time with 0 across the row if unused. Anyone know how I can add these rows for every NJ and stimulus?[image]

The new code:

````
stimulus <- 1:16
factor_attribute   <- paste0("factor_attribute",1:10)
                             
#"Beadiness", "Chewiness", "Contrast", "Crumbliness", "Grittiness","Hardness",
 #"Lumpiness", "Roughness", "Smoothness", "Softness")

all <- expand.grid(NJ = NJ, stimulus = stimulus, factor_attribute = factor_attribute)
all$x30 <- 0
all$x29 <- 0
all$x28 <-0
all$x27 <-0
all$x26 <-0
all$x25 <-0
all$x24 <-0
all$x23 <-0
all$x22 <-0
all$x21 <-0
all$x20 <-0
all$x19 <-0
all$x18 <-0
all$x17 <-0
all$x16 <-0
all$x15 <-0
all$x14 <-0
all$x13 <-0
all$x12 <-0
all$x11 <-0
all$x10 <-0
all$x9 <-0
all$x8 <-0
all$x7 <-0
all$x6 <-0
all$x5 <-0
all$x4 <-0
all$x3 <-0
all$x2 <-0
all$x1 <-0
all$x0 <-0
 
glimpse(all)

tcata3 <- full_join(all, tcata2.df, 
          by = c("NJ", "stimulus", "factor_attribute"), 
          suffix = c("","")) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.),0)```

> head(tcata3)
  ```NJ stimulus  factor_attribute x0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 x16 x17 x18 x19 x20 x21 x22 x23 x24 x25 x26 x27
1  1        1 factor_attribute1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2  2        1 factor_attribute1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3  3        1 factor_attribute1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4  4        1 factor_attribute1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5  5        1 factor_attribute1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6  6        1 factor_attribute1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
  x28 x29 x30 X0 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30
1   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0```
 tail(tcata3)
     ```NJ stimulus factor_attribute x0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 x16 x17 x18 x19 x20 x21 x22 x23 x24 x25 x26 x27
9265 39       16         Contrast  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9266 39       16      Crumbliness  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9267 39       16       Grittiness  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9268 39       16         Hardness  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9269 39       16        Roughness  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9270 39       16       Smoothness  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
     x28 x29 x30 X0 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30
9265   0   0   0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
9266   0   0   0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
9267   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
9268   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
9269   0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
9270   0   0   0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1```
```> head(tcata2.df)
  NJ stimulus X0 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30
1  1        1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2  1        1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3  1        1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
4  1        1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
5  1        2  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6  1        2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
  factor_attribute
1        Chewiness
2        Lumpiness
3       Smoothness
4         Softness
5      Crumbliness
6       Grittiness```
Now I have done the following ```tcata3 <- full_join(all, tcata2.1.df, 
          by = c("NJ", "stimulus", "factor_attribute"), 
          suffix = c("","")) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.),0)

head(tcata3)

tcata3[tcata3$factor_attribute=="factor_attribute1", "factor_attribute"] <- "Chewiness"
tcata3[tcata3$factor_attribute=="factor_attribute2", "factor_attribute"] <- "Lumpiness"
tcata3[tcata3$factor_attribute=="factor_attribute3", "factor_attribute"] <- "Smoothness"
tcata3[tcata3$factor_attribute=="factor_attribute4", "factor_attribute"] <- "Softness"
tcata3[tcata3$factor_attribute=="factor_attribute5", "factor_attribute"] <- "Crumbliness"
tcata3[tcata3$factor_attribute=="factor_attribute6", "factor_attribute"] <- "Grittiness"
tcata3[tcata3$factor_attribute=="factor_attribute7", "factor_attribute"] <- "Beadiness"

tcata3[tcata3$factor_attribute=="factor_attribute8", "factor_attribute"] <- "Roughness"
tcata3[tcata3$factor_attribute=="factor_attribute9", "factor_attribute"] <- "Hardness"
tcata3[tcata3$factor_attribute=="factor_attribute10", "factor_attribute"] <- "Contrast``` but the attributes don't merge and I end up with vectors ```x0:x30``` twice.
````

Comment: I have researched this, I am trying ```crossing``` and ```expand``` but observations keep being filled with 1/0 not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in the comments and [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242968/discussion-between-abdur-rohman-and-niamh), it has been clear that the desired data frame can be obtained by joining two data frames, one with all combinations of the variables including unused factor levels, and another one with only used factor levels. Here are the detailed steps:

1. Create the vectors of the levels of `NJ`, `stimulus`, and `attributes`, and then expand them by using `expand.grid`. You have 39 levels of `NJ`, 2 levels of `stimulus`, and 10 levels of `attributes`.

```
NJ       <- 1:39
stimulus <- 1:16
factor_attribute <- c("Beadiness", "Chewiness", "Contrast", "Crumbliness", 
                      "Grittiness","Hardness","Lumpiness", "Roughness", 
                      "Smoothness", "Softness")

all      <- expand.grid(NJ = NJ, 
                        stimulus = stimulus, 
                        factor_attribute = factor_attribute)
all.x    <- matrix(rep(0, 30*nrow(all)), nrow = nrow(all))
colnames(all.x)  <- paste0("x", 1:30)
all      <- cbind(all, all.x)
glimpse(all)
# Rows: 6,240
# Columns: 33
#   $ NJ               <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16~
#   $ stimulus         <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,~
#   $ factor_attribute <fct> Beadiness, Beadiness, Beadiness, Beadiness, Beadiness~
#   $ x1               <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,~
#   $ x2               <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,~
#   $ x3               <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,~
#   $ x4               <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,~
#   $ x5               <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,~
```

2. `tcat2.df` is the data frame that contains only used attributes.

```
tcata2.df <- structure(list(NJ = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), stimulus = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), X0 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X1 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X3 = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X4 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X5 = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X6 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X7 = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X8 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X9 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X10 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X11 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X12 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X13 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), X14 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), X15 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), X16 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), X17 = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), X18 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), X19 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), X20 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), X21 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), X22 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), X23 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), X24 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), X25 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), X26 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), X27 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), X28 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), X29 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), X30 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), factor_attribute = c("Chewiness", 
"Lumpiness", "Smoothness", "Softness", "Crumbliness", "Grittiness"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

There is a problem with `tcat2.df` . It contains uppercase `x`, which differs from the lowercase `x` in `all`. To fix this problem, `tolower` is used

```
colnames(tcata2.df) [4:33] <- tolower( colnames(tcata2.df) [4:33] )
```

3. Join `all` and `tcat2.df` to get all attributes with `0` across the rows for the unused ones.

```
tcata3 <- full_join(all, tcata2.df, 
                    by = c("NJ", "stimulus", "factor_attribute"), 
                    suffix = c("","")) %>% 
           replace(is.na(.),0)
```

Check :

```
# Compare with tcat2.df[1,]

tcata3 %>% filter(NJ == 1 & stimulus == 1 & factor_attribute == "Chewiness")
#NJ stimulus factor_attribute x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13 x14
#1  1        1        Chewiness  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   0   0   0   0
#  x15 x16 x17 x18 x19 x20 x21 x22 x23 x24 x25 x26 x27 x28 x29 x30 X0
# 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  0
```

Comment: This looks great, thank you. I have 39 levels of NJ, 16 of stimulus, 31 timepoints (x1,x2,x3....) and 10 of attributes. So if I just change the numbers and add here ```all$x3 <- all$x2 <- all$x1 <- 0``` 30 timepoints it might work. Let me try...

Comment: I recommend changing the numbers by using vectorized functions or `apply, not manually to avoid errors.

Comment: OK so this is working well, but when the attributes in my original ```dataframe``` are labeled ```chewiness```, ```softness```, etc so when I join the the 2 ```dataframes``` the attributes don't match up. Do you know how I solve this? I am trying to name them in the code but it comes out just as 1 vector

Comment: Please show your updated code and data so that we can try various alternatives to solve that problem. It's just impossible without data.

Comment: New code above, and ```head``` and ```tail```

Comment: OK, I was able to reproduce your `tcata3` by using your code, but I cannot continue because `tcata2.df` is not available. Could you provide this ?

Comment: My best guess now, with no `tcata2.df` at hand, is that the mismatch happened probably because the order of the columns in `tcata3` is reversed because in your code `all$x30` , not `all$x1`, is assigned first. In my code I used `all$x3 <- all$x2 <- all$x1 <-0` because this way the `0` is assigned from right to left side, so `x0` will be the first column created.

Comment: Ah OK, I just added tcata2.df

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's because in tcata2.df factor_attribute is the last col not the third? I can't tell from your comment if ```xo``` or ```x1``` or ```x30```should be first in the code?

Comment: I moved ```factor_attribute``` ```tcata2.1.df <- tcata2.df %>% relocate("factor_attribute", .after = "stimulus")```

Comment: Please put `tcata2.df` in your question (so that other users can check), not as suggested edit to my answer. I'll try to find what's wrong with it.

Comment: Sorry, it's there now.

Comment: As the rows in the ```dataframes``` match they are just duplicating in the new dataframe.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: so that gives me a joined data frame but the attributes don't merge. So I still have ```factor_attribute1```, etc as well as the original data from ```tcata2.df``` where attributes are named ```chewiness```, etc.

Comment: So the attributes that originally had either ```1``` or ```0``` are not inserting into the ```all``` ```dataframe`` they are adding onto the end. You can see this in your answer above using ```head``` and ```tail```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242968/discussion-between-abdur-rohman-and-niamh).

Comment: I want each NJ and stimulus to have the 10 attributes listed, with ```1``` or ```0``` if they were used and ```0``` across the row if they were completely unused